# Unable to join client pc to domain

Tags: windows

ERROR: An attempt to resolve the DNS name of a domain controller in the domain being joined has failed. Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that can resolve DNS names in the target domain.

I have just installed a fresh windows server 2012 R2 and installed Active Directory. DNS is not installed in this server. Firewall is OFF. Domain is capita.com

Server IP settings are as follows:
ip address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Preferred DNS: 192.168.1.2

I have installed windows 7 Ultimate as client machine and IP settings are as follows:

IP address: 192.168.1.3
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Preferred DNS: 192.168.1.2

Firewall is OFF

Able to ping from server to client using ip address and from client to server as well. Unable to ping server using domain name (capita.com)

Comment: If your AD server doesn't run DNS... then what device is the 192.168.1.2 DNS server, and have you configured the domain name in it according to MS requirements? What records does your zone file contain?

Comment: Well, I saw a lot of videos on YouTube where only AD is installed in the server and client pc is added to the domain. 192.168.1.2 is my server 2012 with AD installed. Domain is configured according to MS requirements.

Comment: But if you didn't install DNS on it, why are you trying to use it as a DNS server from your client? (dcpromo _does_ install DNS by default because AD is very DNS-dependent, some YouTube videos might just forget to mention it.)

Comment: Are you saying, without dns I will not be able to add the client into domain? I think  I should be able to.

Comment: Last January I had taken coaching for MCSE and the guy teaching us had specifically mentioned that I have not configured dns. We were still able to add the client to domain. Am missing something?

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically saying that without DNS, your AD clients will not be able to [find the AD domain controller](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc759186(v=ws.10)#dns-support-for-activedirectory). If they cannot find the DC they can't contact it; and if they can't contact it, they can't set up the AD join. (They might be able to set up a legacy NT4 domain join via NetBIOS, but Win10 no longer support it.) Unrelated to AD, I'm also saying that a system that isn't actually a DNS server doesn't make sense to be used as "Preferred DNS server"

Comment: Starting when Active Directory was introduced with Windows 2000 a domain client will always use DNS to locate a domain controller, even when they are on the same subnet. Only with the older domain system was DNS optional. DNS does not have to be running on the domain controller but but must somewhere in the network and it must have a specific configuration. By default promoting a server to a domain controller will install a properly configured DNS server. Otherwise some manual configuration on the server will be necessary.

Comment: Thank You! I reinstalled AD and DNS and I was able to add the client pc into the domain. Appreciate your help!